# bootstrap() function used in lmer object

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, package

I have a question pertaining to the R presentation by José A. Sánchez-Espigares and Jordi Ocaña entitled "An R implementation of bootstrap procedures for mixed models".

See: http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2009/slides/SanchezEspigares+Ocana.pdf

On slide 22 on the examples they use the function `bootstrap()` (in the slide it is: `sleep.boot=bootstrap(model,B=1000)` ).

The only package they reference is `lme4` but that package does not contain the `bootstrap()` function and I get:

```
Error: could not find function "bootstrap"
```

Does anybody know what package they are using here?

Comment: The presentation was from 2009 so perhaps the function has been superseded with `bootMer` but this, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q3/002614.html, suggests it may be a user written bootstrap function. @BenBolker should know.

Comment: @user20650 FWIW, ?bootMer` says: "The working name for bootMer() was “simulestimate()”, as it is an extension of simulate (see simulate.merMod), but we want to emphasize its potential for valid inference."

Comment: Thanks @user20650, I thought I was missing some key bit of info. If bootstrap() did precede bootMer() I'd expect a note letting us know. I was curious because boostrap() in the example did not require a "FUN" argument like bootMer() does.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that `lme4` never had a `bootstrap()` function, and that it in fact came from code written by the presenters (I have looked for that code on-line before but have never found it). The built-in `bootMer` function tries to do most of what this presentation describes, but doesn't do everything (e.g. it doesn't include an implementation of a [Wild bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Wild_bootstrap)).

If you want to use `bootMer` without specifying a function `FUN`, you might take a look at `confint(.,method="boot")` ... it looks like the summary function that the authors used might have been something like

```
function(x) c(fixef(x),getME(x,"theta"),sigmaREML=sigma(x))
```